# Dynamic css classes (angular like) in phalcon volt

Tags: phalcon, volt

Is there a way to selectively apply a class in volt (the Phalcon template engine) based on variables?

I have come to working in volt from js libraries like Angular and Vue, which have structure like:

```
ng-class="{'active':thing >= 1}"
```

Where a class is applied based on the statement being true. In Volt I could use `if` blocks to selectively render html but was wondering if there is a similar syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<a class="button {% if something == 12 %}active{% endif %}">Link</a>
```

Or you can use ternary operators:

```
<a class="button {{ something == 12 ? 'active' : 'disabled' }}">Link</a>
```

Comment: would the second example work if 'something' were a php variable?

Comment: `something` is actually a PHP variable. Just in Volt there is not $ sign. `something` is same as `<?php $something; ?>`